# How to use columns().search() datatable multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable

I am using below syntax:

```
var array = ["ABC DEF","Test"];

table.columns( 1 ).search(new RegExp(array.join("|"), "i",true, false)).draw();
```

But it is not working. IT always give empty result

I tried

```
new RegExp("("+array.join("|")+")")
```

or

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + array.join("|") + ")\\b", "i");
```

This is what it actually looks in console

```
  /\b(?:ABC DEF|Test)\b/i
```

but empty output always

Is there any issue in syntax? Thanks

Comment: I am getting below output 
/(ABC DEF|Test)/
/\b(?:ABC DEF|Test)\b/i
There may be some other issue in jquery import or project setup

Comment: Have you tried with datatable?

Comment: can you post full code snippet or fiddle demo to simulate this error ?

Comment: sure. I will post full code

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it is working

```
table.columns( 1 ).search(array.join('|'), true, false, true).draw();
```

I am putting it answer for reference.

Thanks